# Clear a cell using a macro in a separate sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I would like to create a macro in sheets that would open a different spreadsheet and clear data from certain cells. I can do it in the same spreadsheet, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it when I have spreadsheet 'A' open and want to delete information on spreadsheet 'B'

Comment: Don't think it's possible with programmatically created macros. You need to write the script manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `SpreadsheetApp.openById('{your_sheet_id}')` (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))) or `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('{your_sheet_url}')` (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String))).

Then you can chain with the usual `getSheet()`, `getRange()` and `clear()` or `clearContent()` methods, e.g.:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxx').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A4').clearContent();
```

Comment: So, I have never used scopes. How do I give authorization to allow the script to run?

Comment: Ok, I removed to current sheet only at top of script and now it works...thanks